# Firefox keeps asking for NT login after location.reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a web application using MVC-3 that uses a user's NT login to authenticate the users of the app. For users of IE, the NT login is automatically detected and I don't have to do anything. If I use Firefox, when I first go to the URL of the app, it asks for my login credentials. And whenever I click on a button on a page (that forces the page to reload via Javascript's location.reload(true) function), it forces me to login again as well. Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?